# Uploading a large file in Blazor WASM without first loading it into memory

Tags: blazor

It seems Blazor WASM will read all contents of an `HttpClient.PostAsync` request into memory before sending it, even when using `StreamContent`.  This is bad for performance and memory.

Does anyone know of a way to solve this problem without having to introduce file-chunking on my server?

**UPDATE**
The problem is in the dotnet runtime, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/cffaa78235ea93d5e3eeb56956579df503e11250/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpHandler.cs#L191-L194).

```cs
Uint8Array uint8Buffer = Uint8Array.From(await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: true)))
```

I'll see if I can work something out using `XMLHttpRequest` instead.

Comment: What kind of file/request are you sending, and how large can it be?

Comment: File uploads, 1 byte to 1GB

Comment: Is the user uploading a file from their file system, or is it something you are generating in the Blazor app to upload to the server?

Comment: User is selecting using an `InputFile` component.